Turbo build clean-up for node.js
I'm using Turbo for my TypeScript project.
If I kill that daemon thread and clean the build folders, then will that affect anywhere in my project?
I want to do a fresh build. So, I'm cleaning up my node_modules and build folders. but as Turbo runs a daemon thread in the background, will that affect anywhere?
